# Query values into a variable in shell script

Tags: sql, postgresql, shell

I have query which gives me result as

```
 app_no
--------
(0 rows)
```

I need to get only the rows part and that too just the number. I am saving the result into a variable but I am not able to parse it.

```
napp=`psql -U postgres appdb -c "select appno from app.apps where properties&2048=1024

cap=$(echo "$napp"|sed -n 's/[0-9][0-9] rows/\1/p')
echo "$cap"
```

I just need number of rows and that too just number.

Comment: Your last sentence is not very clear.  Do you need just the number of rows which match the condition?  And without any extraneous headings and footers, etc?  If so, see my answer.  If not, please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to cut the string *as-is* :

```
napp=$(psql -U postgres appdb -c "
    select appno frpm app.apps
    where properties&2048=1024;"
)
cap=$(echo "$napp" | sed -nr 's/.*\(([0-9]+) rows.*/\1/p')
echo "$cap"
```

But a better solution is the [Jonathan Leffler's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) one

Answer (score 1):

If you need the number of `appno` entries that match, then you should probably use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM app.apps WHERE properties & 2048 = 1024
```

but the answer will always be 0 because the condition is always going to give 0 or false.  You need the same bit twice, either both 1024 or both 2048.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM app.apps WHERE properties & 1024 = 1024
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM app.apps WHERE properties & 2048 = 2048
```

SQL interfaces that insist on headings and summaries are a nuisance when shell scripting.  However, the [psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/app-psql.html) manual suggests that `-q` and `-t` may help (with `-A` too, perhaps):

- `-A` or `--no-align`

  Switches to unaligned output mode. (The default output mode is otherwise aligned.)
- `-q` or `--quiet`

  Specifies that psql should do its work quietly. By default, it prints welcome messages and various informational output. If this option is used, none of this happens. This is useful with the -c option. Within psql you can also set the QUIET variable to achieve the same effect.
- `-t` or `--tuples-only`

  Turn off printing of column names and result row count footers, etc. This is equivalent to the `\t` command.